# what does this error mean "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"

Tags: sql, oracle11g

After executing the code below, i get an ORA-25155 error

```
SELECT p.prod_id, prod_name, prod_list_price,quantity_sold,cust_last_name
FROM products p NATURAL JOIN sales s NATURAL JOIN customer c
WHERE prod_id = 148;
```

Comment: http://awads.net/wp/2006/03/20/back-to-basics-inner-joins/

Comment: Since natural joins join on the same column name, Oracle doesn't let you qualify the columns (since prod_id can belong to multiple tables). Remove the p from p.prod_id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested on a comment, this ORA-25155 error suggests that you're qualifying the column name "p.prod_id" instead of just "prod_id". That is what is triggering your error.

Try this fully working [SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4932f/1). Your query should be:

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_list_price,quantity_sold,cust_last_name
  FROM products
       NATURAL JOIN sales
       NATURAL JOIN customer
 WHERE prod_id = 148;
```

A `NATURAL JOIN` over multiple tables will join one pair of tables, then join the third table to the result and so forth. `NATURAL JOIN` syntax has no explicit join predicate, so the qualifiers aren't used there.

Answer (score 2):

`natural join` in Oracle joins two tables on the columns in each table that have common names. Hence after the join, you shouldn't refer to a column which is common between the tables that have been naturally join with an alias, as the alias is redundant.

This is similar to the way `using()` works in a join clause.

Answer (score 0):

The right command is:

**SELECT * FROM products p NATURAL JOIN sales s NATURAL JOIN customer c**