# Error report - ORA-25155: column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier 25155. 00000 - "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am running this lines, it is giving me the error below.

```
CREATE VIEW student_view AS 
SELECT Student.*, Course.*, Grade.* 
FROM (Student 
      NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade 
      NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Course)
UNION ALL
SELECT Student.*, Course.*, Grade.* 
FROM (Course 
      NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade 
      NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Student)
WHERE Student.StudentID is NULL
```

> *Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
> or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
>
> *Action:   Remove the qualifier

Comment: I would recommend to avoid natural joins. They are obscure and error prone.

Comment: It is an ORACLE error, please update your tags to ORACLE and remove SQL-Server

Comment: Is it possible you could add the tables and sample data?

Comment: Do you have a question about the situation you described? I don't see one. I am being serious, by the way. What do you want to know? Why you get the error? How to avoid it? Something else?

Comment: @TheImpaler - Natural joins are the most natural type of joins (that is why they are called "natural"). They are "obscure" because people don't use them as often as they should. They don't use them more often, because they get this advice, that they shouldn't use them (and therefore they don't learn them in the first place). They are no more error prone than any other kind of join - something is not "error prone" by nature, if it throws errors when people use it incorrectly.

Comment: @mathguy: they are obscure and error prone because the match on column _names_, not on declared dependencies. And if there more then one column matches the result is even more obscure. The matching based on names means that the query can do something completely different tomorrow just because someone added a column that happened to have the same name as an existing one.

Comment: The original query was written on SQLite and I made some changes when I was writing it on Oracle SQL Developer, I tried multiple different things but it doesn't see to be population the table view I am trying to get

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - in a proper data model, "column names" should be in one-to-one relationship to "domains" or "dimensions". The name "id" should be used in different tables only if it represents the same real-life attribute; same for any other column name. Practitioners (including Oracle et al.) have bastardized most of  relational theory, on which relational databases are based; this doesn't mean that  relational theory is wrong. They that sow the wind shall reap the whirlwind.

Comment: @BfromChi - You still didn't tell us what's your **question**. What do you want to know?

Comment: I am trying to fix whatever is causing the error but I can't, that's what I need help with... I started learning SQL two months ago, so it might be a small mistake I am making but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: What is causing the error is easy: You select `student.*` and `course.*`, for example. Let's say both tables have a column `course_id` (which will then be a join column in the natural join). Your `select` is expanded to include both `student.course_id` and `course.course_id`, and that is not allowed; when using a natural join (or an "unnatural" join with the `using` clause) you will get only **one** column named `course_id`, equal to the NVL of those two columns from the base tables. You are violating the syntax for natural joins.

Comment: You can try a simple `select * from [your joins here]` (and you don't need the UNION ALL). Give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does this error mean "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069256/what-does-this-error-mean-column-used-in-natural-join-cannot-have-qualifier)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, natural joins have always been a bad idea. What if someone adds a `description` column to both `COURSE` and `GRADE`? Anyway, columns used in a natural join can't be qualified with a table alias.

```
create table student
( student_id integer primary key
, student_name varchar2(30) not null );

create table course
( course_id integer primary key
, course_name varchar2(30) not null );

create table grade
( student_id references student not null
, course_id  references course not null
, grade varchar2(3) not null );
```

Query:

```
select student_id, student_name, course_id, course_name, grade
from   student 
       natural left join grade 
       natural left join course;
```

Create a view:

```
create or replace view student_view as 
select course_id, student_id, student_name, grade, course_name
from   student 
       natural left outer join grade 
       natural left outer join course
union all
select course_id, student_id, student_name, grade, course_name
from   course 
       natural left outer join grade 
       natural left outer join student
where  student_id is null;
```

Continued on your [other question...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203808/230471)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is some days old but it's a duplicate to
[what does this error mean "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069256/what-does-this-error-mean-column-used-in-natural-join-cannot-have-qualifier)

Just remove the qualifiers Studen.* etc. and just write `select * ...`