# I need to create a view that pre-joins the three tables, including all of the records from student and course tables ( shown below)

Tags: sql, oracle

**-- I am trying to create a view for the tables shown below but my attempt is not successfull.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer!! Where is the mistake here**

```
CREATE VIEW student_view AS 
SELECT Student.*, Course.*, Grade.* FROM (Student NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Course)
UNION ALL
SELECT Student.*, Course.*, Grade.* FROM (Course NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN Student) WHERE Student.StudentID is NULL
;


CREATE TABLE Student(
   StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Name CHAR(50),
   Address CHAR(50),
   GradYear INT
);

-- create table Grade
CREATE TABLE Grade(
    CName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    CGrade CHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY(CName, StudentID)
);

-- create table Course
CREATE TABLE Course(
   CName CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Department CHAR(50),
   Credits INT
);
```

Comment: By the way, the standard string type is `VARCHAR2`, not `CHAR` which is blank-padded for no reason that anybody knows. My advice is to avoid `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the underlying tables before composing them into a view.

Comment: yeah I couldnt do that, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below sequence,

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
   StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Name CHAR(50),
   Address CHAR(50),
   GradYear INT
);

-- create table Grade
CREATE TABLE Grade(
    CName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    CGrade CHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY(CName, StudentID)
);

-- create table Course
CREATE TABLE Course(
   CName CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Department CHAR(50),
   Credits INT
);

CREATE VIEW student_view AS 
SELECT Student.StudentID , Student.Name, Student.Address, Student.GradYear, 
Course.CName, Course.CGrade, Grade.Department, Grade.Credits FROM Student 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grade 
on (Student.StudentID = Grade.StudentID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Course
on (Grade.CName = Course.CName);
```

Comment: Thank you, ut I am getting this ERROR:   ORA-25155: column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier
25155. 00000 -  "column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier"
*Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
           or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
*Action:   Remove the qualifier.

Comment: Query is incorrect. Will change it

Comment: I know this. answer is availble online but I am trying to create the view on Oracle SQL Developer, and something causes this error I posted above. If you can help I would appreciate it

Comment: Provided you. Please use it

Comment: I did... it creates the table when I dont include the first line but all together it gives this error -> 00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"

Comment: Got it. You have to select the columns manually

Comment: Also I am getting NULL values when my view is populated in Query Result. How can I avoid that? Am I providing missing info?

Comment: Provided the query. Please check

Comment: @BfromChi for data-related issues some test data would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected version:

- Defined tables in the right order
- Changed `CHAR` to `VARCHAR2`
- Added foreign key constraints (inheriting data types)
- Removed table aliases not allowed by `NATURAL JOIN` syntax
- Removed redundant brackets from view.

Tables:

```
create table student
( studentid   integer primary key not null
, name        varchar2(50) not null
, address     varchar2(50)
, gradyear    integer );

create table course
( cname       varchar2(50) primary key not null
, department  varchar2(50)
, credits     integer );

create table grade
( cname       references course not null
, studentid   references student not null
, cgrade      varchar2(2) not null
, primary key(cname, studentid) );
```

View:

```
create or replace view student_view as 
select studentid, name, address, gradyear
     , cname, department, credits
     , cgrade
from   student
       natural left outer join grade
       natural left outer join course
union all
select studentid, name, address, gradyear
     , cname, department, credits
     , cgrade
from   course
       natural left outer join grade
       natural left outer join student
where  studentid is null;
```

And just to add, `NATURAL JOIN` is never a good idea in real code.

Comment: This worked, cannot thank you enough!!! Thank youuuuu! @William Robertson